# onClick method handling calls error - is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add some state data into local storage in a method but I get the error:

```
'handleFormSubmit' function is not defined no-undef
```

This is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
    noteTitle: 'sample title',
    noteDescription: 'sample desc'
  }


  handleFormSubmit = () => {

    const { noteTitle, noteDescription } = this.state;

    localStorage.setItem('noteTitle', noteTitle);
    localStorage.setItem('noteDescription', noteDescription);

  };

 render() {
      return (

              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Title"
                onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ noteTitle: e.target.value }) }}
              />

              <textarea
                type="text"
                className="form-control my-4"
                placeholder="Description"
                onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ noteDescription: e.target.value }) }}

              />

              <button onClick={handleFormSubmit} className="form-control">Save</button>
```

I have looked through other post's regarding this issue, it seems so simple but most other issues deal with an extra thing and I don't quite understand why my code shouldn't work.

Comment: Try changing your onClick call?  `onClick={() => this.handleFormSubmit()}`?  I think the parens are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both `this` and `()` to identify that it is local to the class and that it is a function.  Change this...

```
<button onClick={handleFormSubmit} className="form-control">Save</button>
```

To this...

```
onClick={() => this.handleFormSubmit()}
```

[Take a look at a working demo with this fixed.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-8y60i)

If you fork the code above, and change it back to the way you had it, I get the same error as you had...

```
'handleFormSubmit' function is not defined no-undef
```